# Keycloak - How can I remove redirect_fragment from URL?

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloak to secure my web applications, but it keeps this very ugly `redirect_fragment` in the url...

So, instead of having a friendly and intuitive url like this:
http://localhost:8000/#/products/create-new

I have something like this:
[http://localhost:8000?redirect_fragment=%2Fview1&
code=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.YmVjY2ZiYjgtNTk4Ni00MzViLTg2ODktODMwNDgyYTAxNTIyMTQwNDA2NTczMTI4Mw.jD7FkQd-H0o56hByk1CSY7coM3uA5_2UhnzOGVnYWSIsppLkG1MvUhWWcseYN2n9wrTzeo9d2N62qXKPZ4DZssjKy64HNF6tLZ5m3zH1wmHD5WHq8JkbkK3ES-WT62ni7-nypltFwsX62eaWRajdJFgjgPE_oyG-v4xTFM1dUlg
&state=a04ce6e2-a1d0-4b78-8dd1-0e9f2a9df7dd#/products/create-new](http://localhost:8000?redirect_fragment=%2Fview1&%20code=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.YmVjY2ZiYjgtNTk4Ni00MzViLTg2ODktODMwNDgyYTAxNTIyMTQwNDA2NTczMTI4Mw.jD7FkQd-H0o56hByk1CSY7coM3uA5_2UhnzOGVnYWSIsppLkG1MvUhWWcseYN2n9wrTzeo9d2N62qXKPZ4DZssjKy64HNF6tLZ5m3zH1wmHD5WHq8JkbkK3ES-WT62ni7-nypltFwsX62eaWRajdJFgjgPE_oyG-v4xTFM1dUlg%20&state=a04ce6e2-a1d0-4b78-8dd1-0e9f2a9df7dd#/products/create-new)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue..Did u find a solution?